# Calcular la diferencia en minutos entre dos horas

Tags: mysql

Enfrento el siguiente desafío, necesito encontrar la diferencia entre dos `datetime` (order_date y delivered_date), al usar `timestampdiff( minute, order_date, delivered_date )` me calcula correctamente la diferencia en minutos.

Mi problema radica cuando se me presenta el siguiente caso:

```
Order_date: 01/01/2017 23:55:10
Delivered_date: 01/01/2017 00:05:10
```

Entiendo que el problema radica en que las 00 horas en lugar de tener la fecha del día siguiente tiene la misma fecha.

Lo que buscaría obtener seria 10 min pero no es eso lo que obtengo.

Comment: ¿Te da resultados coherentes con el resto de valores que tienes? Me parece que el formato de la fecha puede dar fallos. `SELECT TIMEDIFF('2017-01-01 23:55:10','2017-01-02 00:05:10');` retorna  `-00:10:00`

Comment: En alguna parte tienes un error de concepto. Si la orden se puso a las 23:55 del día 1, no puedes entregar a las 00:05 de ese mismo día. El día 1º empezó a las 00:00 y tiene ya transcurridas 23 horas y 55 minutos, diez minutos más tarde ya no estarás en el día 1º, sino en el día 2. Por tanto, la diferencia a calcular sería esta: `SELECT TIMEDIFF('2017-01-01 23:55:10','2017-01-02 00:05:10');` Si tu programa para casos como estos no está cambiando el día cuando pasan las 00:00 horas, debes revisar la lógica en el mismo para que lo haga.

Answer (score 0):

Obiamente los datos han sido guardados de forma incorrecta debes arreglar eso en programacion pero para que el reporte se genere correctamente debes de ajustar los datos que ya estan en la Base de Datos, solo tienes que cambiar Orders por el nombre de la tabla.

Query 1 para ver que datos tiene un valor erroneo en la fecha de entrega: misma FECHA pero una hora menor de entrega que de orden.

```
select order_date, delivered_date, DATE_ADD(delivered_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS new_delivered_date from orders where HOUR(delivered_date) < HOUR(order_date) AND DATE(delivered_date) = DATE(order_date)
```

Query 2 se ajustan los datos en la base de datos con las mismas condiciones

```
update orders set delivered_date = DATE_ADD(delivered_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) WHERE HOUR(delivered_date) < HOUR(order_date) AND DATE(delivered_date) = DATE(order_date)
```

Eso me recuerda cuando trabajaba en una empresa donde teniamos que corregir datos guardados absurdamente por la aplicacion hecha en una cosa horrible llamada clarion. Pense que nunca iba a volver a recordar eso pero al menos gracias esto se como arreglarlo.